# Android: LinearLayout (horizontal) cuts off last column

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Very simple layout:
I have two TextViews displayed in a single line. The layout is centered on screen and the two strings are set programmatically, The first is a vairaible length string while the second string is either empty or (let's say) "X":

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSelectionName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSelectionAttribute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please note, that the first TextView is ellipsized in order to cut off the string if its size exceeds the TextView.
I expect something like:

"normal text | X"  (centered on the screen)

"extralarge text that must be... | X" (centered on the screen - filling the screen)

But what happens is: The first TextView elipsizes but fills the whole screen(-width) and the second TextView is off screen (wrapped to the next line respectively).
Using "weight" does not help anyway. Setting the layout_height to a fixed value (e.g. 15dp) doesn't help too...

Any advice anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSelectionName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="asdhsagdkgfhgfhghg"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSelectionAttribute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="X"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but as I mentioned above...setting weight doesn't really help because setting weight="1" and with="0" leads to:

"normal text | X"
"extra large text that... | X"

in both cases the layout takes the WHOLE screenwidth and places the first TextView on the leftmost and the second on the rightmost available space...
I tried gravity ("right" for the first TextView and "left" for the second) - doesn't help...

Comment: Edited the answer, use layout_gravity instead of gravity in LinearLayout

Comment: That works! 
(Half :o)
For some reason, the layout isn't layouted after setting the text of the TextViews. That is: the very first time, the text is set, it looks like "normal text | X", after changing the text to "extra large...", the layout takes the same bounderies what will cause the TextView to elipsize much to "early"...it looks like: "extra... | X".
I'm calling "forceLayout()" on both TextViews and everythin' is fine!
Thanks alot, Arun!